# Rails 3 config setting for attr_accessible/protected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment, virtual-attribute

I just spent quite some time trying to resolve a virtual attribute issue in my model. It turned out I'd simply forgotten to add it to attr_accesible in my model. Granted I should have caught it earlier or better should have started the whole endeavor by adding it to attr_accessible in the first place.

To keep this from happening again, is there a configuration setting I can flag to throw an exception on development if I try to mass assign something and validate it when it is protected/inaccessible? I know I can use set `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` to require whitelist for all but my question is more on an individual attribute basis.

The line above for example does not warn me if I have a model with attr_accessible :name then later add :nickname (virtual or not), and try to mass assign it checking for presence=>true. I want it to warn me that I tried to validate a protected attribute through mass assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 3.2 has a configuration option to raise a `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error` in that case

`config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict`

See [Rails 3.2 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#what-to-update-in-your-apps) and the [commit in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/aa2639e746d8af5d7673bbbbbccbe868edeb0161)

Comment: For Rails < 3.2, you can use something along this gist: https://gist.github.com/2027920

Comment: rails 3.1 indeed is where I am at. Thanks.